# Reference child class as parent class variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I'm a newbie hobbyist, so please forgive my ignorance if this is a stupid question.

I'm trying to make a very simple demo of my game project as part of a pitch, and I'm stuck with my characters. I have a `public class Character : MonoBehaviour` for starters, and I'd like to create child classes with override functions. My current `public class TrainingDummy : Character` should be a decent example. I have a separate `CombatDirector` script that's supposed to spawn the characters from an array at start. However, I cannot reference my `TrainingDummy` as a `Character` variable.
I figured I'd be able to reference my characters as `Character` variables, when there are more, but apparently that's not a thing.

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: Please provide a code-sample that illustrates your structure and shows where exactly you have problems.

Comment: If you could [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issue to do that. Let's try to replicate what you explained.

First I generate the `Character`and `TrainingDummy`classes

Character.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Character : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        Debug.Log("This is a character");
    }
}
```

TrainingDummy.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
public class TrainingDummy: Character
{ 
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        Debug.Log("This is a dummy");
    }
}
```

Now onto our CombatDirector.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CombatDirector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Character[] characters = new Character[2];

   void Start()
   {
       foreach (Character character in characters)
       {
            character.MyMethod();
       }
   }
}
```

Now just create three separate `Empty GameObjects` in your scene and add a script to each one of them. The `CombatDirector` script has a public array of two elements of type `<Character>`. However, you should be able to drag GameObjects containing `Character` OR `TrainingDummy` scripts to the array slots in the `Unity Editor`. If you place one of each and press Play, you'll see that the array elements despite being referenced as `Character`, maintain the values corresponding to their class instances, so two different messages will be printed in the console. I hope I made myself clear.

[image]

[image]